# Timestamp has Decimal?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to get a timestamp in Javascript, but it's returning a decimal. When I checked the timestamp with an online converter it's actually correct. I've never seen this format before.

```
var currentTS = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

How can I get a whole number and why is it returning a valid timestamp with a decimal?

Thanks

Comment: `getTime` returns milliseconds, so dividing by 1000 returns seconds. Something like half a second is obviously something with a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result is not divisible by 1000 you will get a fractional result, its not returning a *timestamp*, its just returning a number.

If you want to truncate you can; `parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use parseInt on a number - use Math.floor

```
Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
```

The result of that is a UNIX Timestamp, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean the function is returning a floating point rather than an integer value.

To convert a floating point number to an integer in JavaScript, use Math.round(num).